# TableView with simple 2 or 3 cells scrolling is leaking

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uitableview

I've custom tableview cell and whenever I scroll, it's leaking memory as shown in instruments image below. It's the same effect with customtableviewcell scrolling.

I've downloaded several apple sample projects and its same result. memory leaks whenever I scroll any tableview list(even for 2 or 3 cells) or customtableviewcell!

I'm using ARC, but it seems its leaking memory and I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

I'm using reuseidentifier custom tableview cell

```
 static NSString *NotesCellIdentifier = @"NotesCell";
            notesCell = (EditingTableTextViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NotesCellIdentifier];
           if (notesCell == nil)
           {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EditingTableTextViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            notesCell = editingTableTextViewCell;
            self.editingTableTextViewCell = nil;
           }


#import "EditingTableTextViewCell.h"

@implementation EditingTableTextViewCell


@synthesize label, textViewField;

- (void)dealloc {
    //  [label release];
    //  [textField release];
    //  [super dealloc];
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{

    if(editing){
        [self.textViewField setEditable:YES];
    }else{
        [self.textViewField setEditable:NO];
    }
}

@end
```

is this due to my custom cell holding onto old properties? I can't dealloc in ARC so how do i clear old property values?

My instruments screen shot is:

[image: TableList/CustomTableViewCell scrolling leaks]

can anyone help me to identify the memory leak?

Thanks in advance.

Rama

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple came back today and accepted it as a bug: ID# 11106828 & ID# 10710601. I'll post update here when I get a response.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement this in your custom cell:

```
-(NSString *) reuseIdentifier {
    return @"NotesCell";
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't know if that is going to fix your leaks, but at least you are going to have reusable cells.

Comment: I'm already using re-usable cells. I'm surprised that its showing leak even for 1 cell. this is all happening when i simply scroll and nothing else! unfortunately its the same result with apple downloaded projects!!!

Comment: If you are using ARC don't worry. If your app doesn't crash, the objects are probably going to be released on the next run loop. If your app would crash, that would be a problem. I know that you are using reusable cells, but if you don't implement the above method in your class, the cells are going to be recreated instead of reused. You can check that by printing a message in this if (notesCell == nil){ }

Comment: if it gets reclaimed later then its brilliant. But I just reported this bug @ Apple. we'll see what they come up with..